# Dijital Ocean spaces listObjects not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, fileserver

My application.yml

```
## PostgreSQL
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://myip:5432/db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
    username: wqeqe
    password: qweqwewqe$qwewqe
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true

---
server:
  port: 8085

## DO properties
do:
  spaces:
    key: mykey
    secret: mysecret
    endpoint: digitaloceanspaces.com
    region: myregion
    bucket: mybusket
```

My read config read appication.yml

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "do.spaces")
public class DoConfig {

    @Value("${key}")
    private String doSpaceKey;

    @Value("${secret}")
    private String doSpaceSecret;

    @Value("${endpoint}")
    private String doSpaceEndpoint;

    @Value("${region}")
    private String doSpaceRegion;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 getS3() {
        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(doSpaceKey, doSpaceSecret);
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(doSpaceEndpoint, doSpaceRegion))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).build();
    }

}
```

My service

```
@Override
public List<TemplateDto> getAll() {
   return (List<TemplateImage>) templateImageRepository.findAll();
}
```

My repo

```
@Repository
public interface TemplateImageRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<TemplateImage,Long> {
}
```

Hi everyone I am using this project dijital ocean spaces but the problem `listObject` images don't return null. What is the problem please help me I am new working is the file servers.
Thanks !!!

Comment: Do you mean the vendor *Digital Ocean*, and their product *Spaces*? Your Question could use some more details.

Comment: My problem Spaces in the DijitalOcean